# Send Email to Rep_abv__c field of Update Records

Tags: apex, email, email-template, singleemailmessage, send-email

I have below method where Publish operation occurs. Here I can get in Debug log that SetToAddress is coming as Null hence Publish operation not working. For the rest everything is fine. Please let me know why this is coming as null.

Publish Method:

```
public void Publish()
{   Set<String> tempSet = new Set<String>();
   List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
chkpublish=true;
    List<Compliance_Incident_abv__c> selIncs = (List<Compliance_Incident_abv__c>)contr.getSelected();
    for(Compliance_Incident_abv__c inc:selIncs)
    {

        inc.status_abv__c = 'Open';
        inc.Publish_Date_abv__c = Date.today();
        if(inc.Rep_abv__c !=null)
            inc.OwnerId = inc.Rep_abv__c;
    }        
    update selIncs;
     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for (Compliance_Incident_abv__c myContact : selIncs) {

  // Step 1: Create a new Email
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = 
  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 String UserTo = [select Name from User where Id=:mycontact.Rep_abv__c].Name;
  // Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email

  sendTo.add(myContact.RepEmail_abv__c); 

   system.debug('@mails@2'+sendTo);

  mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
 system.debug('@mails@3'+sendTo);
  // Step 3: Set who the email is sent from

  mail.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
// mail.setTargetObjectId(myContact.Rep_abv__c);
 mail.SetSaveAsActivity(false);
  // (Optional) Set list of people who should be CC'ed
  List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();

  //ccTo.add(myContact.ManagerEmail_abv__c);
  ccTo.add('saikat.neogy@cognizant.com');
  mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
  mail.setTargetObjectId(mycontact.Rep_abv__c);
//  mail.setBCcAddresses('saikat.neogy@cognizant.com');

  // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables!
  /*EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Initial Notification to Rep' limit 1];
        mail.setTemplateId(et.id);*/
  mail.setSubject('Initial Notification to Rep');
  String body = 'Dear ' + UserTo + ', ';
  body += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
  body += '<br>New ABS Incidents have been generated in iREP. Please review these incidents with your DM or Applicable Manager. There is no other action for you to complete in iREP.';
  body += '<br>To view your open incidents:<br>';
  body += '•       Log into the iREP app on your iPad and select “Compliance Incidents”<br>';
  body += '•       Select the “Open Incidents” View in the Compliance Incidents Home Page.<br>';
  body += '•       Click the Incident ID to view your incidents If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.<br>';
  mail.setHtmlBody(body);

  // Step 5. Add your email to the master list
  mails.add(mail);
system.debug('@mails@'+mails);

  }
 // Step 6: Send all emails in the master list*/
 Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Successfully Published'));
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with this code which i would like to highlight and provide some suggestions.

**1. sendEmail() method is inside of for loop**

This will hit the governor limit of 10 sendEmail method calls per Apex transaction if the user selects 11 or more Compliance_Incident_abv__c records and invoke the publish() method.

**Suggestion:** You can move the sendEmail() method outside of the for loop.

**2. Using Id instead of Email**

mycontact.Rep_abv__c is a lookup to User(assumption based on usage in code). But you are adding this Id into List sendTo and setting this list as mail.setToAddresses() which will eventually fail.

**Suggestion:** You can modify the code block as below to make use of Email Id of User

```
String UserTo = [select Email from User where Id=:mycontact.Rep_abv__c].Email;

// Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email
tempset.addall(sendTo);
if(!tempset.contains(UserTo))
{
    sendTo.add(UserTo);
    system.debug('@mails@2'+sendTo);
}
else {
    continue; 
    system.debug('@mails@1'+sendTo);
}
mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
```

But a better suggestion would be to use the user id in mail.setTargetObjectId() which will not be counted as an email invocation.

Now lets come to the original question of sendTo getting null. As i stated in above, the setToAddresses can take List of email addresses not Salesforce Ids.

Hope it helps to understand better.

Comment: Thanks that's the case!Can you please suggest me how to keep sendemail out of for loop? Whenever I need to send emails I need it in for loop I guess. Can you please change my code?

Comment: Move this declaration before starting of for loop List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); and move the Messaging.sendEmail(mails); outside of for loop after its closing curly brace.

Comment: Yes did as you said. Now the issue with SetToAddress. Though it's not salesforce ID, it comes as NULL. Updating my code here.

Comment: still you are adding myContact.RepEmail_abv__c to sendTo and setting it to setToAddresses instead of Email of User.

Comment: RepEmail is a Formula(text). That I can't change?

Comment: Hey Thanks Man!! Changed that in String and got resolved!!! Great!!